# Bind input focus to a function in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following directive

```
.directive('uiFocus', function() {
  return function(scope) {
    elem.bind('focus', function() {
      scope.$apply(function() {

      });
    });
  };
})
```

I want bind the focus to a function in the controller

```
$scope.resetBorders = function() {
  document.getElementById("main1").style.border = "none";
  document.getElementById("bk1").style.border = "none";
  document.getElementById("main2").style.border = "none";
  document.getElementById("bk2").style.border = "none";      
};
```

I tried using `resetBorders(), scope.resetBorders() and $scope.resetBorders()` but it didn't work.

What am I suppose to use here? Is there a "better" way doing that?

Thanks

Comment: Yes! Use `ngStype` - DON'T manipulate the DOM like this (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) You can also apply the stype using a class and set that class using `ngClass`

Comment: Pass `elem` as argument in `return` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('uiFocus', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'yoururl/asd.html',
    controller: function($scope) {},
    controllerAs: 'controllerAlias'
  };
});
```

Comment: This question is on the low quality post list. Provided this code solves the problem, if you expand upon your answer and add comments as to how it is working, you are likely to get up votes.